Python 3.x fails to load a .so file in TCL through tkinter
Python 3.x (3.9.7) is giving the following error if I try to load a shared object TCL file.
If I run manually it works.
Manual method:
shell> tclsh
%load blah.so
%cmd_in_blah

Python method:
from tkinter import *
tcl = Tcl()
ret = tcl.eval("load blah.so")


Gives an error here >>>:
*** Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00002ae034fc8d00 ***
Abort

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

The error is in python, so try reporting it as a bug to python. The python interpreter crashing instead of raising an error is a bug

I have also filed a ticket on Python: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/118051

First, we need to know whether the two Tcl interpreters are the exact same version or not. It's very easy to have several different versions about, and using the wrong version can cause crashes (they shouldn't, but reality...)
Get the exact version number from the result of package require Tcl or from the tcl_patchLevel global variable.
If you're loading the code into the same version of the Tcl runtime, and have also matched whether it is a 32-bit or 64-bit build, then the problem is definitely somewhere within Python. I do not know what that might be doing to intercept calls into the dynamic library loading. Or... the library might be detecting something like an extra environment variable and altering its behaviour somehow.
Debugging crashes with as little information as you provided is hard!

Hard is an understatement. It is simply impossible.
